# How to use React.usecallback?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

i have a function like below to be called on button click using react and typescript.

```
function Parent () {
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = React.useState(false);
    const handleClick = () => {
        setIsOpen(open => !open);
    }
    return (
        <button onClick={handleClick}>click me </button> 
    );

}
```

How can i rewrite `handleClick` method using `React.usecallback` method?

could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: `setIsOpen`  is already optimized for performance, unless you have any other reason don't use `useCallback` to set state. Check this [When to use useCallback](https://medium.com/better-programming/when-to-use-callback-function-of-setstate-in-react-37fff67e5a6c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just wrap the functional and add our **isOpen** to the list of dependent variables, since it will change every click time.

```
const handleClick = React.useCallback(() => {
  setIsOpen(open => !open);
}, [isOpen]);
```